# Nested @each observers in EmberJS (e.g. rows.@each.cols.@each.label)

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to build an observer to detect when changes deep in a table model occur. I can get notifications on "rows.@each.label" but not on "rows.@each.cols.@each.label".

```
App.Row = Ember.Object.extend({
    init: function () {
        this.set('cols', []);
    }
});

App.Col = Ember.Object.extend({
    label: null
});
    var doneWithSetup = false;
var table = Ember.Object.create({
    rows: [],
    colLabelChanged: function () {
        if (doneWithSetup) console.log("IT WORKED! I got notified when a col label changed");
    }.observes("rows.@each.cols.@each.label")
});

var row = App.Row.create({});
var col1 = App.Col.create({ label: "Label 1" });
var col2 = App.Col.create({ label: "Label 2" });
row.get('cols').pushObject(col1);
row.get('cols').pushObject(col2);
table.get('rows').pushObject(row);

// OK, lets try this observer out...
doneWithSetup = true;
col1.set('label', 'some new label');

// FIXME: how do I get colLabelChanged to fire???
```

You can try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4H2ya/3/

Am I doing something wrong or are multi-level @each observers not supported?

Comment: After more testing, I think this may be an EmberJS bug. I've opened an issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/922

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in EmberJS 0.9.8.1: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/541

Answer (score 1):

Nested @each is not supported according to the documentation.

```
Note that @each only works one level deep. You cannot use nested forms like todos.@each.owner.name or todos.@each.owner.@each.name.
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

Answer (score 0):

Ran this code and got "IT WORKED! I got notified when a col label changed " in the console. (Using Chrome 19.)

http://jsfiddle.net/4H2ya/

So multiple @each is in fact supported, and you're doing nothing wrong. Which version of Ember are you using?

Comment: Good catch. Its not working on label changes, but it DOES notify when you do table.get('rows').pushObject(row), which is the "IT WORKED!" you saw. I updated the fiddle to surpress printing until the objects are setup. http://jsfiddle.net/4H2ya/3/

Comment: I've updated the question to fix this. But the question still remains, why don't I get notified when a col.label changes?